# PDO: Remove duplicates of the query's results

Tags: php, pdo

When I execute a statement with PDO, it always returns the results with duplicates, i.e. one version with the numeric index and the other with the column name.

For example:

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=test;host=localhost','root','');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

try {
    $stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM Person');
    $ret = $stmt->fetchAll();
    print_r($ret);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Error: '.$e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

I get:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [name] => Stanchi 
        [0] => Stanchi 
        [surname] => Jacopo 
        [1] => Jacopo)
    [1] => ...
)
```

But I just want:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [name] => Stanchi 
        [surname] => Jacopo)
    [1] => ...
)
```

How should I do?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: you are getting result in both numbered and associative array. you can fetch only associative array too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument of your fetchAll call schould be `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`

See http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: Thanks, and if a want only the numeric indexes, what is the fetch style?

Comment: with `PDO::FETCH_NUM` you will get an numeric indexed array

Comment: What if i'm using foreach ($this->db->query($q) as $i ) ?

Comment: I think you can pass this as the second argument. Not 100% sure tho